# Python - Extracting and streaming video frames using flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I newbie to Python, i want to extract video frame, detect egde and stream it using Python. I tried this but simply nothing appear. What is wrong with this code ?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def gen():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('a.mp4')
    while(True):
        img = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 200, apertureSize=3)
        vis = img.copy()
        vis /=2
        vis[edge != 0] = (0, 255, 0)
        merge = np.concatenate((img, vis), axis=1)
        cv2.imwrite('out.png', merge)
        frame = open('out.png', 'rb').read()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/')
def video_feed():
   return Response(gen(),
                mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you imported flask and opencv?

Comment: I'm already imported.

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues in your code:

The first one was in this line:

```
img = cap.read()
```

This is because `cv2.VideoCapture(src).read()` returns 2 arguments. The first is boolean, it is `True`, when the image exists or `False` if it does not. The second argument is the current frame. So, you have to replace your line by something like:
`ret, img = cap.read()` or `img = cap.read()[1]`

Also this line caused `TypeError`:

```
 vis /=2
```

It is happening, because odd integers after division by 2 obtain float type. To run your corner detector successfully, you have to import the `numpy` library and replace this line with another one, that does not convert image array elements to float:

```
vis = numpy.trunc(vis / 2)
```

Comment: Many thanks, i'm solved my problem with add "ret" var in my code.